# Handling Android libraries wih resources from ant (crunch folder triggers an error)

Tags: android, ant

An Android project refers to Android library project. Everything works fine, when I build the signed project from menu (Android Tools/ Export Signed Application Package).  Since Google Play Services wouldn't work with a Debug signature, I have to build the signed project many times, where entering passwords is really annoying. For that reason I prefer to use Ant and set up the passwords in `local.properties`, so that everything can be done in a single click.

I created `build.xml` (via "`android update project`") for both main and library projects. If the library project 
does not contain resources, everything works smoothly. However, if the library has resources, I get an error:

```
invalid resource directory name: library_project_path\bin\res/crunch
```

***Cleaning the projects does not help***: get same message.

Disable "`Build automatically`": still `crunch` directory upsets the build!

You will really make my day by suggesting a solution to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you move the contents of crunch to res and then delete the crunch folder, it should work when you rerun ant. That's what worked for me, anyhow.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937540/android-ant-error-invalid-resource-directory-name-bin-res-crunch/)

Comment: It certaintly will, but the whole idea is to avoid replication and have shared resources in a shared library available to several apps. Somehow Android plugin manages to do it though "Export App Package", why we can't make it in ant?